# Ecommerce event parameters not showing on GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

First of all sorry, I am not a developer.

We implemented 7 dataLayers for ecommerce events. There are no errors on GTM and all the tags are firing normally. The events are showing in GA4, but the parameters don't.

Here are a few images:

[Example of a tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiL4Y.png)

[Example of the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSf5A.png)

[Example of the tag firing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFuCh.png)

[Example of another tag firing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmtfd.png)

[No parameters on GA4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlFU0.png)

I followed this guide for implementing the events: https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-set-up-ecommerce-tracking-in-ga4-google-analytics-4/

The dataLayers were implemented by a developer (this part seems fine based on the GTM images above, no?)

I tried to turn on "Send ecommerce data" on the tags, but it didn't help. I understood that it's not really something necessary anyway.

Edit:

Items show in DebugView, but not under parameters

['Items' shows in DebugView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXxOI.png)

Comment: Can you provide the datalayer on the product page? You can open the devtool -> console and execute the command `copy(dataLayer)` and paste in here if it is not too sensitive on your end.

Comment: Example: [ { "gtm.start": 1514357775289, "event": "gtm.js", "gtm.uniqueEventId": 1 }, { "event": "view_item", "ecommerce": { "currency": "USD", "items": [ { "item_name": "sample", "item_id": "sample", "price": 149, "item_brand": "sample", "item_category": "sample", "item_category2": "sample" } ] }, "gtm.uniqueEventId": 2 } Thanks!